# Is it possible in java that same variable name with different datatype?

Tags: java, variables

Is it possible in java that same variable name with different datatype.
i have written following code

```
/*TelnetClient client = new TelnetClient();//serverName,
port,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),port);
client.connect(serverName, port);*/
Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),port);
logger.info("Just connected to " + client.getLocalAddress());
OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
```

TelnetClient class variable name and Socket class variable need to be same.

Is there any way to do this like in C++ there is #define functionality is there

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what you're asking about?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Would you please clarify it as best you can?

Comment: I need to create Server client application using Telnet and TCP. In that application i written code like this `/*TelnetClient client = new TelnetClient();//serverName, port,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),port);
                client.connect(serverName, port);*/
                Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),port);`

Comment: every time i need to comment each code so how will i do that

Comment: @Sush Your example will be easier to understand if you edit it into your original question rather than pasting your code into a comment.

Comment: Why do your variables need to have the same name? Is there a reason you couldn't name them `telnetClient` and `socketClient`?

Comment: @Ben if i do that then code will be duplicate

Comment: Duplicate means, i need to write same code for different variable

Comment: @Sush Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. You can't have two different objects of different types in the same scope with the same name, as dasblinkenlight's answer explains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, as long as the scopes of the two variables do not overlap.

This will compile and run:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    {int a = 5;}
    {String a = "5";}
}
```

However, the desirability of doing something like the above is highly questionable: the compiler does not care, but the human readers of your program will have harder time understanding what your code means. Readability is a major concern in production software development, so generally people do not write this kind of code.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, two variables can have the same name but the variables should be in different scopes (i.e. the scopes do not overlap each other).

But keeping same name for two different variables is not considered a good practice as it can be dubious for the users that are going to work on your code in future.